# Minimised pages are pulled up automatically in Google Chrome when searching on Google

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-search

I use Google Chrome on OS X. When I visit the Virgin Media homepage and search on Google, I can select search results.

These results will be opened in a new window, which I then minimise to the bottom right of the Dock.

When I enter another search in the old window, and select a result, the minimised window will be pulled up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Which browser are you using to search on Google? Can you explain step-by-step what is needed to reproduce this issue? When you *type* something in a Google browser window, the other browser windows suddenly become maximized again?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using Virgin media homepage and google chrome as my browser.I search on google, get results, select a search result, it opens,I minimise to bottom left. Then have original search screen showing. If I click on any other search result say to compare with the first, it doesn't open it as a new window but pulls up the minimized search from the dock. Hence I cannot compare anything on 2 or > searches at once.

Comment: Minimize to bottom left? When you select a search result, does it first open in a new window? Because, what you describe now … how can you have the original search screen open after you click a result? Are you basically saying that whenever you want to open a new window, it always uses the minimized one? Is that it?

Comment: Sorry, minimises to bottom right-doh! yes, when I select a search result it opens in a new window which I can minimise. Hence the original search is left open, but when I open a second page it automatically pulls up the minimised page and does NOT open a new page.Hence I can't have > 1 search open at a time.

Comment: Okay, I finally got you. I cannot reproduce this though. When I open Google results in a new Window (i.e. by holding `Shift` when clicking them), a new window is always opened. Have you set up Google results to open in a new window automatically? Does that only happen for the Virgin Media homepage or plain old `google.co.uk`?

Comment: Thanks so much for being patient. I didn't know about the 'shift' when clicking new pages and this works every time. Thankyou so much.

Comment: You're very welcome! I posted that as an answer so you can accept it :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment thread, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> will always open up a new window and not pull up a minimized one.